# (Java) Getting error with 2D Game

Tags: java, eclipse, 2d

I'm having an issue with my 2D game that I am following a tutorial for.  I've scanned my code several times and cannot seem to resolve it.  Sorry if my question sounds stupid, but I do welcome any help whatsoever.
Here's my source:

```
package game;


import gfx.SpriteSheet;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.DataBufferInt;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUD = 1L;

    public static final int WIDTH = 160;
    public static final int HEIGHT = WIDTH/12*9;
    public static final int SCALE = 3;
    public static final String NAME = "Game";

    private JFrame frame;

    public boolean running = false;
    public int tickCount = 0;

    private BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    private int[] pixels = ((DataBufferInt) image.getRaster().getDataBuffer()).getData();

    private SpriteSheet spriteSheet = new SpriteSheet("SpriteSheet.png");

    public Game()
    {
        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(WIDTH * SCALE, HEIGHT * SCALE));
        setMaximumSize(new Dimension(WIDTH * SCALE, HEIGHT * SCALE));
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH * SCALE, HEIGHT * SCALE));
        frame = new JFrame(NAME);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.add(this, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.pack();

        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    private synchronized void start()
    {
        running = true;
        new Thread(this).start();
    }
    private synchronized void stop()
    {
        running = false;
    }

    public void run() 
    {
        long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
        double nsPerTick = 1000000000D / 60D;

        int ticks = 0;
        int frames = 0;

        long lastTimer = System.currentTimeMillis();
        double delta = 0;
            while(running)
            {
                long now = System.nanoTime();
                delta += (now - lastTime) / nsPerTick;
                lastTime = now;
                boolean shouldRender = false;


                while(delta >= 1)
                {
                    ticks++;
                tick();
                delta -= 1;
                shouldRender = true;
                }


            try {
                Thread.sleep(2);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {

            }

                if(shouldRender)
                {
                frames++;
                render();
                }

               if(System.currentTimeMillis() - lastTimer >= 1000)
               {
                    lastTimer += 1000;
                    System.out.println(frames + ", " + ticks);
                    frames = 0;
                    ticks = 0;
               }

            }
    }
    //Updates all of internal variables and logic and stuff.
    public void tick()
    {
        tickCount++;

        for(int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++)
        {
            pixels [i] = i + tickCount;
        }
    }
    //prints the updated logic.
    public void render()
    {
        BufferStrategy bs = getBufferStrategy();
        if(bs == null)
        {
            createBufferStrategy(3);
            return;
        }
        Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), null);

        g.dispose();
        bs.show();

    }

    //Main method
    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
        new Game().start();
    }



  }
```

---

```
package gfx;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class SpriteSheet
{
    public String path;
    public int width;
    public int height;
    public int[] pixels;

    public SpriteSheet(String path)
    {
        BufferedImage image = null;

        try 
        {
            image = ImageIO.read(SpriteSheet.class.getResourceAsStream(path));
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if(image == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        this.path = path;
        this.width = image.getWidth();
        this.height = image.getHeight();

        pixels = image.getRGB(0, 0, width, height, null, 0, width);

        for(int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++)
        {
            pixels[i] = (pixels[i] & 0xff / 64);
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(pixels[i]);
        }
    }


  }
```

---

And here's a link to my video tutorial I'm using:  [Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o7pfq0W3e4I)

I'm using eclipse on a 64 bit operating system(Windows).
Again, any help would be greatly appreciated, and thank you.

EDIT: 
Error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1348)
    at gfx.SpriteSheet.<init>(SpriteSheet.java:21)
    at game.Game.<init>(Game.java:34)
    at game.Game.main(Game.java:144)
```

Sorry, forgot error message. XD

Comment: Could you be more exact than "I'm having an issue"?

Comment: Oh snap sorry forgot the error message.. XD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is telling you what's wrong: Your image path is wrong. The image path must be given relative to the class files location.

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't seem to find the issue with path.  Can you be a little bit more specific than "path"?  Thanks, -Captain

Comment: @CaptainMadbeard: where is your image file in relation to your class files? Is all in a jar file?

Comment: I have a "res" folder with a SpriteSheet.png in it. The res folder is located in my referenced libraries

Comment: @CaptainMadbeard: good deal. Important lesson learned: read the error and exception messages critically as they usually contain very useful information. Much luck!